# How to draw 2 regression lines on the same graph using Seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

Using value as x axis, count as y axis, a regression line could be drawn as follows

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.jointplot("value", "count", data=df).plot_joint(sns.regplot)

plt.show()
```

I'd like to know how to draw another regression line using *value as y axis*, *count as x axis* on the same, like the below

[image]

Comment: did you try using sns.regplot?

Comment: Note that jointplot doesn't return an ax, but a figure-level grid. You can add lines via `g = sns.jointplot(...)` and `g.ax_joint.plot(...)`.  Your post is missing essential information about which regression line you want to draw.